# recyclerview is empty when back pressed from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

On Fragment1 i have onClick method, when i click the button, i got the recycleview list of items. When i click the item in recycleview(use getPlaceFromItem method), i go to the Fragment2. if device is phone then put the 
Fragment2 in container1, but if device is tablet(landscape) then i put Fragment2 into container2 next to Fragment1 in container1.

Now, when i press back button when device is phone, i get empty recycleview.

In addition i check orientation of the screen and when the device is phone and i am in Fragment2(i.e Fragment2 in container1), then when the screen will be landscape i will put into container1 Fragment1, and into container2 at Fragment2. My problem is how can i cut Fragment2 from container1 and put it into container2.

**Main Activity :**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

                View v = findViewById(R.id.container2);
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container1, new FragmentA())
                        .commit();

        }

 @Override
public void getPlaceFromItem(Place place) {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putDouble("lat", place.getLat());
    bundle.putDouble("lng", place.getLng());
    Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
    fragment2.setArguments(bundle);

    if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTab)) {

        View v = findViewById(R.id.container2);
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
       .replace(R.id.container2,fragment2)
       .addToBackStack(null)
       .commit();
    }
    else {


        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container1, fragment2)
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
    }

}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}



     @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

            // Checks the orientation of the screen
            if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {


                    View v = findViewById(R.id.container2);
                    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container1, new Fragment1())
                             // The next row is a problematic!!!
                            .replace(R.id.container2, new Fragment2())
                            .commit();      

       } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
 }      
    }
```

Comment: is resyclerview is on same container fragment?

Comment: Yes, on the same container fragment.

Comment: Can you please add the code of your Fragment `onCreateView` and `onResume` methods?

Comment: Okay, I will add code later. Thank you

Comment: I added more code, please see it.

Answer (score 8):

Remember when a fragment is popped out from back stack it comes back with no view. So you have to attach the view again.

I recommend for you to keep track of the main View in Fragment in order to avoid views from recreating. This way once you come back to the fragment with the RecyclerView it will be there. The code would look like this.

```
public class BlankFragment2 extends Fragment {

public View myRoot;

public BlankFragment2() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    if (myRoot == null) {
        myRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment2, container, false);
    }
    return myRoot;
}
```

}

Comment: i will check later and tell you what happened. Thank you

Comment: Before a minute i put more code, can you see it please.

Comment: Sorry this is a completely new question and code i think you should calificate first the last one , and then add a new question.

Comment: I will try your idea today and back with result.

Comment: I checked the code, i have the same rows as you suggested, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

.addToBackStack(null) remove it from code

i hope it will work for you

Comment: i suggest that fill recyclerview in onResume() or onPause() again

Comment: what do you mean? can you let me an example please?

Comment: I added more code and explanation. Can you see it please.

Answer (score 0):

Add `.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getCanonicalName())` or `.addToBackStack("anyString")` to save fragment instance. Also use `add` method, not `replace` when you add new fragments.

Comment: Did you use `add`? `replace` will remove your last fragment add new one. `add` just will add new one.

Comment: I will add more code later. In used replace, because there are yet other fragment in the container1.

Comment: I added more code and explanation. Can you see it please.

Answer (score 0):

when you are adding your first fragment you should not use addToBackStack(null).

for first fragment write like this

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.container1, FragmentA)
    .commit();
```

for other fragments you should use

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.container1, FragmentB)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Before a minute i added more code and explanation. Can you see it please.

Comment: It does't help.